# Workflow - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

```
[CRON],"1537161146.7513",https://crm.amfrost.com/,Instance,"2018-09-17 10:42:26","",[STARTS]
[INFO] Workflow - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed
[INFO] RecurringInvoice - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed
[INFO] SendReminder - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed
[INFO] MailScanner - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed
[INFO] Scheduled Import - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed
[INFO] ScheduleReports - not ready to run as the time to run again is not completed
[CRON],"1537161146.7513",https://crm.amfrost.com/,Instance,"2018-09-17 10:42:26","2018-09-17 10:42:26",[ENDS]
```

Answer (score 2):

Vtiger minimum cron frequency is 15 minutes.
You can set cronjobs frequency via Settings.

Go to CRM Setting > Other Settings > Scheduler
or
http://yourcrmurl/index.php?module=CronTasks&parent=Settings&view=List

if you need decrease frequency lower than 15 minutes change it directly from vtiger_cron_task  table.
just change frequency from 900(in seconds) to desired value.
for example If you need to scan every minute set value to 60.